# How to replace all special characters and spaces in a table column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table named "contacts" with below fields

```
id | phone_mobile

1  | 9988011223
2  | 00-12-123456
3  | 91-8876980987
4  | (91) 88990099777
```

I want a select query which will return below output

```
id | phone_mobile

1  | 9988011223
2  | 0012123456
3  | 918876980987
4  | 9188990099777
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a known set of characters you can use `replace()` function chaining something as

```
mysql> select replace(replace(replace('00-12-123456','-',''),'(',''),')','');
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| replace(replace(replace('00-12-123456','-',''),'(',''),')','') |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0012123456                                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So in your case it could be

```
select 
id,
replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_mobile,'-',''),'(',''),')',''),' ','') as phone_mobile
from table_name
```

If there is a long list of characters to be replaced then its better to use the application level to do the job since the chaining of replace becomes really messy.